# How to get equally distanced rows based on date from a django query?

Tags: python, django, date

I am writing a django application where I am collecting data from database. My model contains a datefield called date.

I want to fit the dates into a line chart. As there can be hundreds of dates in the table. I want to minify the data by selected 10 equally distanced dates from the entire table.

For example, if my rows contain dates 1/09/2013 - 20/09/2013, I want to get:

```
1/09/2013
3/09/2013
5/09/2013
7/09/2013
9/09/2013
11/09/2013
13/09/2013
15/09/2013
17/09/2013
19/09/2013
```

Here is my model:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
```

Here is my query:

```
data = Model.objects.all()
```

I want to do it in the safest way possible since dates present in my database can be irregular.
How do I divide data based on `data.date` like this? Is there a prebuilt function for django? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to return slice with 10 items that will look like this `['1/09/2013', '1/09/2013']`?

Comment: You must write custom `ModelMenager` for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:** Simply get the difference between first and last date, divide by 10 to get day diff between 2 records. And then loop to get 10 records.

```
data = Model.objects.all().order_by('date')

n = data.length()
date_first = data[0].date
date_last = data[n].date

days_diff = (date_last-date_first).days

diff= days_diff/10;

# Now store date in a list

date=[]
for i in range(0,10)
     date.insert(i,date_first + i* datetime.timedelta(days=diff) )
```

Comment: in date_last = data[-1].date negaive quering is not allowed in django. I get error in this line.

Comment: I have edited the solution. Just have a look. I did coz python allows negative indexing.

Comment: One more: date[i] = date_first + i* datetime.timedelta(days=diff) I get error: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @Elisha512 , just have a check now

Comment: Yep! Works now! Thanks!

Comment: @Elisha512 Feel Privileged to help you. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has an answer, but the most surefire, bug-free way would be to just rely on `pandas` built in functionality.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> start = pd.Timestamp('2013-9-1')
>>> end = pd.Timestamp('2013-9-20')
>>> periods = 10
>>> freq = (end - start + pd.Timedelta(days=1)) // periods
>>> dates = pd.date_range(start, periods=periods, freq=freq)
>>> dates
DatetimeIndex(['2013-09-01', '2013-09-03', '2013-09-05', '2013-09-07',
               '2013-09-09', '2013-09-11', '2013-09-13', '2013-09-15',
               '2013-09-17', '2013-09-19'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='2D')
>>> dates.to_pydatetime().tolist()
[datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 3, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 5, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 7, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 9, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 11, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 17, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 19, 0, 0)]
```